# Login and authentication system in a service (wcf) based application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

i want to design a authentication system for a service oriented application.
i have a wcf service based asp.net application

Answer (score 0):

Do some reading on

WCF Patterns and Practices [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731059(VS.90).aspx).

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647374.aspx) out as well.

Hope that helps.